# How to check multiple fields in SQL Server for null data

Tags: sql-server

I can write a query like this to check whether a column contains `NULL`
for example address.

```
SELECT CustomerName, ContactName, Address
FROM Customers
WHERE Address IS NULL;
```

Assuming I need to check about 25 columns in a table for `NULL`, is there a way to write it apart from repeating the columns one by one?

Comment: Short answer - no. You or "something" must add each column name into the query.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky - I don't know the meaning of all what you are writing. Is the select statement I posted not clear enough for you to understand what I am asking?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to avoid listing out all 25 fields, but if you just want to check for a single non `NULL` field, you may chain `COALESCE` as follows:

```sql
SELECT CustomerName, ContactName, Address
FROM Customers
WHERE NOT COALESCE(field1, field2, ..., field25) IS NOT NULL;
```

The above logic would return any record where at least one of the 25 fields be `NULL`.

Comment: ... or rather where ALL of the 25 fields are NULL ? Also the columns need to have the exact same datatype for this to be possible.